# red circle with white x on all drives on all pcs

Tags: windows-10, icons

This happened a few days ago, i have three computers running windows 10 pro x64 1903 and all drives, even new ones added, usbs, iphones all have these x's on them seen in the picture. but it happened on all three computers at the same time. i tried clearing the icon cache which would deleted all the files but that did not fix the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use drop-box? This has been [reported as a drop-box related bug](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Files-folders/Bug-Fixed-amp-Removable-Drive-Icons-Have-Red-X-Overlay/m-p/354269). This will usually happen to network drives when they are mapped as perpetual but the icon won't update after the connection is established.

If you're not using drop-box, pretty much any other file syncing service can be a culprit - so make sure anything you're using is updated and that you are logged in. If one of these utilities is causing you issues, you can exit the service completely, refresh Windows Explorer, then start the service again.

Comment: It was dropbox and i was was enrolled in the beta releases somehow, but yet this fixed it for all computers.